# Scientific notation String to BigDecimal

Tags: java, parsing, bigdecimal, scientific-notation

I have external hardware which will send me their values with scientific notation like this: `5.312E+03`
However I receive this as a String and need to cast it to a BigDecimal.
doing this:

```
String value = "5.312E+03";
BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal(String);
```

I get the following value `5312`. BigDecimal will remove the `E+03` and also remove the dot from the original Value. And I was wondering why and how to force BigDecimal to not do that.

When I give the variable `value` the following: `5.312` it will stay like this as BigDecimal.

Also just giving `5.312E` will naturally cause a `NumberFormatException`

Here is some StackTrace to show this Behaviour:

```
2017-06-13 09:05:13,713 TRACE [SCTLaboratoryDevice] [] (SCT) received data: 600+6.513E+03
2017-06-13 09:05:13,714 INFO  [SCTLaboratoryDevice] [] (SCT) filtered value: 6.513E+03
2017-06-13 09:05:13,718 DEBUG [SCTLaboratoryDevice] [] (SCT) send WebSocket{amount=TcpAmountImpl [value=6513, unit=null]} on channel SCT
2017-06-13 08:57:34,351 TRACE [CTLaboratoryDevice] [] (SCT) received data: 600+6.513E+03
2017-06-13 08:57:34,351 INFO  [SCTLaboratoryDevice] [] (SCT) filtered value: 6.513E
2017-06-13 08:57:34,352 SEVERE [SCTLaboratoryDevice] [] (SCT) null: java.lang.NumberFormatException
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:596)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:383)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:806)
2017-06-13 08:56:28,260 TRACE [SCTLaboratoryDevice] [] (SCT) received data: 600+6.513E+03
2017-06-13 08:56:28,260 INFO  [SCTLaboratoryDevice] [] (SCT) filtered value: 6.513
2017-06-13 08:56:28,260 DEBUG [SCTLaboratoryDevice] [] (SCT) send WebSocket {amount=TcpAmountImpl [value=6.513, unit=null]} on channel SCT
```

Do I have a mistake in my thoughts about BigDecimal and scientific notation or how do I make BigDecimal accept the original value `5.312E+03` correctly?

Comment: `5.312E+03` = `5.312 * 10^3` = `5312`

Comment: And if you change the "E+03" to "E+02" you get 531.2, correctly. So basically, there are no problems...

Comment: Closing as "can't be reproduced" as the closest reason to "no actual problem".

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you for letting me know. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The BigDecimal has been created correctly.

5.312E+03 is the same value as 5312.

The only difference is how it is being displayed.

Comment: I have a similar problem, even though it's created correctly it is annoying for unit tests. E.g.: Expected: is <100> but: was <1E+2>

Comment: Can I recommend comparing it as a Number in your asserts, that way you won't care about the display.

Comment: Certainly, how exactly did you had this in mind? Currently we have something like: `assertThat(bigDecimal1, is(bigDecimal2)`. For now I've fixed my test by calling toPlainString on both... but I'm not happy with this workaround so curious to learn what you have in mind.

Comment: I would start from the basis that: `assertEquals(new BigDecimal(100), new BigDecimal("1E+02"));` passes without issue

Comment: Both `assertEquals(new BigDecimal(100), new BigDecimal("1E+02"));` and `assertThat(new BigDecimal(100), is(new BigDecimal("1E+02")));` fail with the same error on my machine...

Comment: your `assertEquals` failure surprises me, because it works for me, and underneath it will call the `.equals` method which should return true when `compareTo == 0` and vice versa.